# How to limit display size of a datalist?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datalist

I have a datalist with a bunch of numbers and would like to limit the display size of the menu to 5 options, but as I understand this can't be done with html/css, so what are my options?

```js
// Generate an array from 1-144 in increments of 0.5
var length = [];
var list = document.getElementById('lengthDatalist');

for (let i = 1; i <= 144; i+= 0.5) {
  length.push(i.toFixed(1));
}; 

//For each item in array length, create an option in datalist
length.forEach(function(item){
   var option = document.createElement('option');
   option.value = item;
   list.appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
<input name= "lengthInput" id="lengthInputID" list="lengthDatalist" />
     <datalist id="lengthDatalist"></datalist>
```

Comment: you only want 5 choices or 5 shown at a time?

Comment: To clarify I want to limit the display to 5 items. For example typing 1 would display every result instead of limiting it to the first 5